# Keep docker container running while debugging inside the container

Tags: docker

In my Dockerfile, I have `CMD java -jar a.jar`. Then I started the container. Then I want to ssh into the container and kill the a.jar process and run `java -jar b.jar`. So I ran `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash`, then killed the process, but the container stopped immediately. Is there a way that I can keep the container running after I kill the main process so that I can run another process?

Comment: You're killing the main process with PID 1. Once it's killed, the container will basically finish its job (which is the main process) and will stop. You can spawn several apps as background jobs from the main process.

Comment: You can just start a new container with the new process.  That's not supposed to be an especially expensive process.

Answer (score 3):

Your container is dying because the process that starts the container and keep it running is the process id 1. Since you killed it the container died.

If you want to start the container and kill the java process, you can override the CMD in docker run and append a command that will run even if you kill the java process.

E.g: `docker run ... mycontainer java -jar a.jar & sleep infinity`

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can do this:

- run container with `CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]`
- then do `docker exec` into the container to run `java -jar a.jar`
- kill that using `kill` or interrupt that using `ctrl + c`, and then run `java -jar b.jar`

Answer (score 0):

try the option `--sig-proxy=true` when you `exec` into the container.